# Angular2: How to access to form validation fields in Component.ts

Tags: validation, angular, angular2-forms

For example I have a form ( not with FormGroup ) and view lookes like this

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate>
     <label>Email</label>
     <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="player.email" class="form-control" name="email" #email="ngModel" required>

     <!-- with #email code, now, in view, I have variable with name email!!! -->
</form>
```

With #email tag I declare a variable with name 'email' and with this variable I can check for validation errors. For example

```
 <div [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine"
               class="alert alert-danger">
            email is required
 </div>
```

How can I access this variable in my component class?

Comment: Almost the same, but it realy helps. Good solution in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use it by declaring ViewChild as below in your component :

```
export class MyCompoment {
  @ViewChild('email') email: ngModel;

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.email);
  }
}
```